# There is no featured image in my post in wordpress multisite theme

Tags: multisite, post-thumbnails

I have a multi-site word press theme and it has front page as post pages and i have inserted also the featured images in particular post , but it didnt appear the  images still. 
 After all there is no error message also. I can found it works in localhost but not in server.
Plz help me.

Comment: What Theme are you using? Does the Theme use the core Featured Image (i.e. Post Thumbnail) functionality, or something else (e.g. TimThumb)?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic, for being a Theme-specific user-support issue. Downvote for failing to follow up on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

network admin -> dashboard -> settings -> upload settings -> and check "images, video, music" boxes.

If you want this in CTP you have to work arround because there is some issues with that.

Hope it helps, 
CheerZ!.

Answer (score 0):

If it is on a sub site and uses timthumb, the theme will have to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/wordpress-multi-site-get-a-featured-image-from-another-blog/ ,I have actually solve this with php ,I have just query the right post meta table and pull featured image data.